# Quick java clarification needed for student

Tags: java

I am reviewing a piece of code that looks like this:

```
float x = 9;
float y = 5;
int z = (int)(x / y);
```

---

Question:

I am wondering why there is a second int on line 3 when it is already declared that z is an int. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Otherwise, the compiler will say "Hey! WTH are you doing, you're assigning a float to an int."

Comment: Why not remove it and *see what happens for yourself*?

Answer (score 6):

The result of the division `x / y` is a `float`.  Java doesn't allow you to assign to an `int` variable like this, with a narrowing primitive conversion (here, to an `int`), because this would potentially lose precision.  But Java will allow you to do this with an explicit cast, in which Java assumes you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare the result `(x/y)` to be `int`, otherwise you are trying to set the value of an `int` variable with a `float`, which generates a compiler error.  This purposeful declaration is required when reducing the precision or range of a number.

Answer (score 0):

According to compilers we are kiddo's.. therefore he(the compiler) wants us to explicitly mention that what we are doing is on purpose and not a mistake, hence we need to specify explicitly..

These are the two scenarios:
1) With (int):

```
**Program:**
class fox
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    float x = 9;
    float y = 5;
    int z = (int)(x / y);
    System.out.print(z);
}

}

**Output:**
# 1:   hide   clone   input   8 seconds ago
result: success      time: 0.07s    memory: 380224 kB     returned value: 0

input: no
output:
1
```

2) Without (int):

```
    **Program:**
    class fox
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        float x = 9;
        float y = 5;
        int z = (x / y);
        System.out.print(z);
    }

    }
   **Output:**
    Main.java:7: error: possible loss of precision
        int z = (x / y);
                   ^
      required: int
      found:    float
    1 error

    # 1:   hide   clone   6 seconds ago
    result: compilation error     
    // see the compiler cannot understand that we wish to do it purposefully,,
```

Comment: Whether this produces a compiler warning or error may vary depending on various project and compiler settings.

Comment: It is an error, not a warning.  The code will not compile.

Comment: ya i made that change...thanksss... by the way not every compiler will give an error, there are some who just show a warning and carry on..